# search bar that updates after every letter inputted html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, search, searchbar

So I have a site that has a ton of buttons, but I want to make a search bar that after every letter, it compares the contents with the id or alt of each button, so basically if I type “he”, it will show all things that have “he” in the first 2 letters of their name and not show the others

Anyone know how I would be able to do something like that?

I tried making a form that compares it when I click the submit button, but I cant seem to figure out how to make it so it updates after every letter, and I also cant figure out how to compare it properly either as it just didnt update anything:
`<input id="Search"></input> <button class="searchItem", id="123">123</button> <button class="searchItem", id="122">122</button> <button class="searchItem", id="213">213</button>`

```
 const SearchBar = document.getElementById("Search");

SearchBar.addEventListener("input", updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {

const searchItems = document.getElementsByClassName("searchItem");
[searchItems].forEach(el => { 
  
  if (el.id.startsWith(e.value)) {
    el.style.display = 'block';
    print('what ok')
  } else {
    el.style.display = 'none';
    print('doesnt work')
  }
 });
};
```

Comment: Can you _show_ us what you tried (as opposed to explaining it briefly)? In short, you may want to look at the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), and perhaps the [`String#startsWith` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new contributors visit [ask] for tips on how to write a question that best enables the community to provide you with assistance.  It would be helpful if you included some example(s) of what you've tried so far, and included information as to _why_ it isn't working toward your needs, including the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and any error messages you may be seeing.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Could I do something like ```inputName.addEventListener(“input”, Event => { for all of the buttons with class name, if it starts with the input value it sets its display to block, or if not, it sets it to none}); ```?

Comment: Or I could use the event type of updateValue too i think

Comment: I added the code I just made, but of course its not working either and I dont really know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e` in your event callback is the input event object, but you want instead `e.target.value` to get the current value of the `<input>`:

```js
function updateValue(e) {
  ...
  if (el.id.startsWith(e.target.value) { 
    ... 
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i already figured it out, but this is similar so i will mark as answer